# JDBC Mysql Timezone issue with Day Light saving

Tags: java, mysql, timezone, jersey, mybatis

I am facing an issue with MySql Select statement for date field with Day Light Saving.

> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3

The only solution worked for is setting `serverTimezone=GMT-6` in MySql Connection String. But this I will need to change when daylight saving is not there.

If I am trying to set `serverTimezone=America/Denver` then it give same error.

> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3

My Database time zone is **America/Denver**

My project is Jersey project with Java 8 and Mybatis.

I tried multiple suggested solution but nothing is working concrete. Please guide me on this.

Comment: With respect, *it didn't work* is not a helpful description of a fault. What happened? Did the server refuse the connection? Did it deliver incorrect results?  Is the MySQL column declared `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you this error?

Comment: @Joni I cannot show you the code. There is date column with value `2019-03-10 02:04:13`. The issue is with these types of records only. The issue is coming with Select Query. If I execute the query on the Mysql database directly it works.

Comment: Well that time is wrong, on 2019-03-10 the clock was never 02:04:13 in America/Denver. It skipped from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00  http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/denver

Comment: What behavior would you expect: should your query return the time as 03:04:13?

Comment: Ok Understood the issue with time. There is record in Database with this date and time I expect the select query should return the record.

Comment: @AjaySharma I couldn't reproduce it. What is the driver version? You should try the latest [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java). And which time zone is your project running (i.e. local time zone)? If you could provide a small repro like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues), you'll get a definitive answer quickly.

Comment: @ave I am using the latest driver. DB Column value is `2019-03-10 02:04:13` timezone is **America/Denver**

Comment: @AjaySharma So, both the server and the client are on the same timezone? Then I have no idea what is going on. If you need further assistance, consider providing a demo app. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be tracking moments in your database in a column of type `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL version 8. This type is akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Using JDBC 4.2 or later, exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 2 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt  = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

The `ZonedDateTime` class automatically adjusts for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). If 2 AM does not exist on a certain date on a certain date with a “Spring ahead” DST cutover, the time-of-day is adjusted to 3 AM.

Oddly, JDBC 4.2 requires support for `OffsetDateTime` but not the more commonly used `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. So convert.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.withZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Notice that using this approach means we don’t care about the current default time zone on The server or the client, nor do we care about the current default time zone in your session.